# Are two random variables X and Y independent of each other if their covariance and correlation are both zero?

Tags: regression, econometrics

Does both the Cov(x,y)= 0 and the Corr(x,y)= 0 for random variables x and y to be independent. Is it possible random variables are correlated whilst the covariance is zero?

Comment: Is this self-study or for a course? Try searching for the definition of covariance. That should help.

Comment: If the covariance is 0 the correlation between the variables must also be 0 and vice versa.This question differs from the title. If the title is the actual question the answer is no. Their exist random variables that are uncorrelated and yet are not statistically independent.

Comment: If the question is not like the title but like the text then it is not a duplicate, at least not in relation to the current referred previous question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. In order to see this, note that

$Corr(x, y) = \frac{Cov(x, y)}{\sqrt{Var(x)}\sqrt{Var(y)}}$

Since $Cov(x, y)$ is zero, there is no way that the fraction can become positive/negative.